# Понимание систем контроля версий

Tags: контроль-версий

Как побороть дискомфорт при использовании систем контроля версий?

Сколько раз не пытался понять, не получается. Как люди работают с системой контроля версий и считают такой подход к разработке удобным?

Внесли правку в код - ввели команду в терминале для пуша - всё записалось. 
Ни разу не встречал систему контроля версий, которая предлагала бы онлайн-разработку с примерно таким подходом:

1. Заходим на онлайн-ресурс
2. Создаём проект
3. Указываем данные своего удалённого сервера для хранения кода
4. Начинаем работу...

При этом при сохранении файлов, каждая правка автоматически создаёт дополнительные копии проекта с различными версиями кода. И есть возможность к возврату к любому состоянию проекта в любое время.

Такие системы контроля версий, как я понимаю, не существуют. Не могу только понять почему, ведь этот подход в десятки, а то и сотни раз удобней(для меня, возможно для кого-то ещё). Не нужно ничего настраивать, скачивать, работать в терминале...хоть сам бери и начинай стартап-проект.

Comment: такое уже есть - gitlab. Даже проще:) это как github. Там файлы можно редактировать онлайн. Каждое сохранение будет делать коммит. А можно взять что то вида https://c9.io/

Comment: и прямо без терминала всё автоматически будет сохраняться на моём сервере и после сохранения все мои правки будут сразу на странице?

Comment: Если настроить автодеплой, то да.

Comment: Я тоже не понимаю -- "`как люди работают с системой контроля версий и считают такой подход к разработке удобным`" (правда, по другим соображениям). Поэтому для себя в основном пользую `tar` (время от времени играясь с git  (сейчас) и пытаясь понять, как с ним на самом деле правильно работать (или убедить себя, что мне это в самом деле удобно)).

Comment: В GitLab есть интеграция с Koding, это онлайн-IDE. Позволяет вести всю разработку онлайн, ничего не устанавливая и не настраивая.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ответ на основной вопрос:

> Как побороть дискомфорт при использовании систем контроля версий?

Практика работы в команде прежде всего поможет.  Часто возникают внештатные ситуации, которые сложно обработать без git:

- **необходимость отката**
  При использовании git делается в одну команду = 10 сек, ручное рукоблудство не даёт гарантию корректного отката и делается дольше, при долгоиграющих проектах версий необозримо много. Откатить одинаково просто как файл, так и версию в целом.
- **разработка командой одного проекта**
  Тут вообще — я просто не представляю иного способа разработки одного большого проекта всем вместе. Очень удобно пришёл на работу — выполнил одну команду = 3 сек, и у тебя уже есть всё что сделали твои коллеги. Уходишь с работы — потратил 3 сек — все твои изменения в репе.
- **просмотр истории эволюции кода из IDE**
  А это вообще мегафича. Код в мозгу прямо живым становится, трёхмерным) Очень красиво всё отображается в NetBeans, например — сразу всё понятно, что к чему. И ещё это всегда помогает найти виновника костыля.
- **защита от потери сорцов**
  Как то когда я был на первом курсе и ещё не знал про системы контроля версий: писал месяц проект — фреймворк для 3д графики. И тут бах — подцепил вирус из ВК, который мне его удалил к чертям собачьим. Как было обидно — не передать.
- **простой деплой между серверами**
  Деплой проекта на боевой сервер (если мы о серверной разработке и интерпретируемом серверном языке) — делается в одну команду (`git pull` или `git clone` — кому как больше нравится). Никакого гемора, плясок с бубнами и путаницы с правами на файл.
- **ветвление версий**
  Даёт функционал, чтобы твои разработки в проекте и разработки группы прогеров не влияли на основной ход разработки и сливались только при стадии завершения задания в основную версию. При том, что изменения можно по прежнему спокойно отправлять в репу (работают все другие плюсы).
- **руководство разработкой**
  Руководство программистами может превратиться в ад без системы контроля версий с коммитами. Потому что нету быстрого способа посмотреть, что коллега сделал, нету качественного представления его трудов, невозможно на глаз оценить правильность трудов. А когда есть система - по истории коммитов можно очень быстро понять, что сделано хорошо, что сделано не очень, что надо быстренько подправить, где провести разъяснительную беседу. Красивое отображение в IDE истории коммитов, с подсвеченными изменениями/удалениями/вставками - это дополнительный сильный бонус, оценивать работу становится очень комфортно.

Так вот, необходимость обрабатывать эти внештатные ситуации в 100 раз перевешивает любой дискомфорт. И потом, к гиту быстро привыкаешь и уже считаешь его эталоном логичности. Если используем git из консоли, — не забываем про консольный интерфейс — кнопка <kbd>Tab</kbd> печатает команду за тебя по первым символам, стрелочки вверх и вниз вводят в поле ввода предыдущие набранные команды — очень удобно.

> Внесли правку в код — ввели команду в терминале для пуша — всё записалось. Ни разу не встречал систему контроля версий, которая предлагала бы онлайн-разработку с примерно таким подходом:

А вот это уже не система контроля версий, а UI её оборачивающий.

Вопрос актуальный, поскольку при столкновении с cvs/git тоже испытывал определённый дискомфорт. Рушатся шаблоны. Но только потом осознал, насколько git крутая штука.

Comment: *"простой деплой между серверами"* - настройте нам такой, чтоб в одну команду? :-)

Comment: Пожалуйста, не путайте интерпретируемые языки с общим случаем. Было бы все так просто - никакой CI бы не появилось.

Comment: >настройте нам такой, чтоб в одну команду

Comment: Там настраивать нечего - ставим гит на сервер. 
Стратегия git pull: делаем единожды клон проекта, создаём конфиги и единожды конфигурируем (конфиги разумеется в .gitignore лежат). После этого деплой идёт единой командой git pull.
Стратегия git clone: 
Создаём баш скрипт/пхп скрипт, ложим его в папку ~/deploys , в нём команда клона. Конфиги в самом проекте, но их несколько - деплой скрипт создаёт симлинк на конфиги и на папки статики.
При обоих стратегиях подтягиваются изменения БД после пулл/клон хуки. clone больше подходит для деплоя на несколько серваков, так как работает железно.

Comment: Повторяю: *"Пожалуйста, не путайте интерпретируемые языки с общим случаем"*.

Comment: Вы и компилятор на сервер ставить будете? А если проект без IDE не собирается (такое бывает со странными технологиями) - то и IDE на сервер поставите? И билд проекта будете вешать на пулл-хук?

Comment: С деплоем компилируемого не знаком. Подозреваю Java. Но вот вопрос - кто мешает скомпиленый проект также хранить в гите, и при деплое заменять его целиком? То есть скомпилил, запушил -> сдеплоил -> новая версия. Но возможно у меня в этой тематике знаний нет.

Comment: А кто будет его компилить? Особенно если он из нескольких частей состоит?

Comment: Да даже webpack и scss/less уже не вписываются в вашу схему нормально.

Comment: Лид программист у которого локально развёрнуты все нужные компоненты и IDE . Который спулил труды своих ребят, протестил что надо. Если пушит программист которому не дали такую возможность - он и не компилит: при возможном деплое изменений не происходит.

Comment: - scss/less 
У нас есть PHP scss компилер - работает в демоне, если видит что scss модифицирован, компилит его. Таким образом даже никаких изменений в деплойнике. Аналогично и для js-минификации.

Comment: То есть вы свели задачу деплоя к задаче доставки файлов и говорите что гит "делает простой деплой" :) Вообще-то, проблема деплоя как раз и состоит в том, чтобы лиду не надо было компилить все руками каждый раз как надо заливать изменения на сервер.

Comment: Ну в разных конторах лиды разным занимаются. В чём проблема компиляцию на фоне запустить, получить уведомление когда она прошла, и затем пушнуть?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41863/discussion-between-pavel-mayorov-and--).

Comment: Если у вас деплой делается `git pull` или `git clone` - он делается далеко не лучшим образом.

Comment: @Nick Volynkin, факты, аргументы? У 2х проектов, прибыль которых 3 мил/месяц (и ещё 50-ти с меньшей прибылью) - он делается лучшим образом через гит. Деплой должен быть простым, как топор - это помогает сделать git.

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр всё же прибыль проекта не говорит о его сложности.

Answer (score 12):

При таком подходе один разработчик за день может нагенерировать (5—30) * 8 коммитов (это примерно). Десять разработчиков за год нагенерируют (5—30)*8*200*10 коммитов. Это примерно 80 000 — 480 000 коммитов на среднестатистический проект в вакууме. Причем в дальнейшем такая детализация впринципе не важна и будет мешать, потому что основные вопросы которые задают системе контроля версий "Как исправили этот баг?" "Какие были внесены изменения чтобы реализовать эту фичу?" "Кто последним редактировал этот файл и зачем? Что он еще при этом менял?".

При ответе на эти вопросы никому не интересно что вы 100 раз сохраняли файл внедряя новую фичу, переписывая раз за разом какие-то куски чтобы добиться ожидаемого поведения. Важно то в каком состоянии проект был до начала работы над фичей и после. Остальное будет информационным шумом.

Грамотно отметить эти этапы работы над кодом в системе контроля версий помогают коммиты и ветки. Все эти инструменты позволяют структурировать историю изменений ПО так, чтобы её было удобнее анализировать. Чтобы эту историю было еще удобнее анализировать разработчики в команде договариваются как именно они будут использовать СКВ (в какие моменты создавать ветки, в какие коммиты, может ли в один коммит входить исправление бага и разработка новой фичи (sic!), как будут сливаться ветки или переноситься изменения между ветками и т.д.). Все это требует дополнительной ручной или полуавтоматической работы (IDEшки помогают делать что-то мышкой например). Да это отвлекает от безудержного полета мысли программиста при написании программ, но это сильно помогает если программы долго живут и поддерживаются.

Answer (score 9):

У системы контроля версий, которую предлагаете вы, был бы один серьезный недостаток - она не предполагает [атомарных операций - коммитов, changeset-ов](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control#Atomic_operations).
Т.е. изменения в файлах она сохранит, но никакой гарантии что проект будет целостным и рабочим на момент этого сохранения - нет.

Это было достаточно серьезной и актуальной проблемой во времена CSV/VSS - тогдашние системы контроля версий, хоть и научились сохранять изменения в файлах, но не еще не доросли до понятия changeset-а (набора изменений).

Поиск, например, "стабильной версии на вчерашнее утро" превращался в труднопроходимый квест - приходилось буквально угадывать время, на которое надо было забрать состояние. В некоторых случаях стабильного состояния вообще не было - все смешивалось в кучу при одновременной работе нескольких человек.

С тех пор системы управления версий начали работать с атомарными наборами изменений - changeset-ами. Разработчики настолько устали от мешанины из отдельных файлов, что именно наличие changeset-ов стало причиной резкого роста популярности SVN как замены CVS.

Принять решение о том, что должно войти в changeset, может только сам разработчик - система управления версиями просто не состоянии оценить необходимость создания changeset-а.

Поэтому операция коммита до сих пор требует ручного нажатия кнопки.

Answer (score 3):

Пока вы работаете в одиночку система контроля версий вам может понадобиться ну максимум для отката к какой-то точке, когда всё работало. В целом система svn так и развивалась - каждая ветка лишь отдельная папочка, сильно упрощая можно сказать, что ребятам просто надоело копировать эти папочки.

Проблемы начинаются когда у вас уже набралась команда разработчиков и присылать проекты в zip архиве по email и вручную копировать изменения вам надоело (фу, какая мерзость). Вот тут уже на помощь mergetool и прочие инструменты современного разработчика - вам надо объединить ваши усилия для работы над проектом, а не над тем, как же его запустить после изменений условного Васи.

Ещё одним несомненным плюсом являются коммиты. Коммит - это некоторое состояние с текстом, который описывает изменения. Это опять же помогает при командной работе. Посмотрели чего новенького в dev ветке, слили себе, сидите довольные, всё работает (хотя "всё работает" - это  больше задача тестов). Ваша последовательность "каждая правка автоматически создаёт дополнительные копии проекта с различными версиями кода" по факту и есть коммит. Только не на одну правку, а на несколько в рамках задачи. И с описанием.

Ещё плюсом в командной работе является ответ на вопрос "кто тут наговнокодил". Пишешь `git blame`, указываешь файл - вуаля, сразу всё видно. Никто не скроется от тестировщика.

Хочешь статистику по тому кто сколько кода написал? Тоже всё из коробки.

Логгирование изменений? Всё есть

Ну а, скажем, есть у меня с десяток проектов. Возвращаюсь я к тому, что делал год назад. Чешу бороду, пытаясь вспомнить что ж тут я вообще делал то.. `git log` и всё тайное становится явным!

Или позабыл я что я там прикрутить и доработать пытался. `git branch` - все ветки со всеми доработками

В крупной компании, когда много чего теряется никогда не пропадёт код, который кто-то написал, но забыл залить в master ветку - `git branch --no-merged`. И всё.

Comment: "В целом система mercurial так и развивалась" - не меркуриал, а svn

Comment: @vitidev точно, попутал. Спасибо, исправил

Answer (score 3):

То,  чего вы хотите, вполне достижимо,  в  теории. И для этого не нужно реализовывать новую систему контроля версий, можно базироваться на существующей. К примеру, на Git. Нужный вам техпроцесс вполне реализуем в новом клиенте и даже не требует от других разработчиков подстраиваться под его способ работы.

Выглядеть это могло бы следующим образом:

1. Вы создаёте проект на онлайн-сервисе,  получаете URL репозитория
2. Вы запускаете клиент, делаете ветки (для долгосрочной истории, куда мелкие комнаты без большой надобности отправлять не надо), например `master` и `development`. Созданные таким образом ветки считаются главными.
3. Вы переходите в ветку, в которой будете работать (`development`)
4. Вы вносите изменение и... Начинается магия. Клиент обнаруживает изменения, видит, что он в главной ветке,  туда писать нельзя. Он делает отдельную,  вашу личную фича-ветку, которая будет только локально, и пишет коммит в неё.
5. Вы вносите ещё изменение. Клиент обнаруживает его, видит, что он в фича-ветке и добавляет изменение в неё.
6. Когда приходит время слить изменения в главную ветку (и нажимается соответствующая кнопка), все изменения фича-ветки сводятся клиентом в один коммит (squash через отдельную ветку), отправляются в главную ветку (fast-forward) и происходит переключение на главную ветку. Фича-ветка удаляется (но из-за особенностей Git ещё будет доступна пару недель, клиент может запомнить хэш её верхушки).

Этим достигается:

- Простота интерфейса снаружи. Вроде.
- Совместимость с привыкшими коллегами.
- Лёгкость поиска по истории, без кучи мелких изменений, от которых кроме как их автору никому пользы нет. Да и автору спустя месяц такая детальность будет только мешать.

Вот только такого клиента ещё нет. Никто не сделал.

Answer (score 0):

Для меня система контроля версий это как вернутся в прошлое где на тот момент все работало. При вашем способе:

> этом при сохранении файлов, каждая правка автоматически создаёт дополнительные копии проекта с различными версиями кода. И есть возможность к возврату к любому состоянию проекта в любое время

Например, мне неясно куда возвращаться(имею ввиду на какой момент)...да и автоматизировать все не получится.

Comment: То есть всё дело именно в том, что есть у правки название - "поменял это, поменял то" и это принципиально для вас? Мне казалось, что достаточно какой-нибудь временной шкалы, на которой представлены все версии файла, их можно открыть, посмотреть, откатить назад. Но никто не мешает рядом с кнопочкой сохранить добавить опциональное поле для комментария правки и вот у вас уже тоже самое, что стандартный репозиторий, но без траты времени на терминал и прочее.

Comment: @Floyat, до контроля версий нужно просто дорасти. Вернее, дорасти должны Ваши проекты. Когда я решил освоить GIT, скачал его и... не осилил. Мой код был ещё достаточно простым, а использование GIT — сложным. Затем, когда я стал делать по нескольку изменений в день в разных файлах своего старого кода, я понял: это ПЦ. Скачал Tortoise SVN (графический клиент, встраиваемый в Проводник Windows), установил, создал там нужные ветки (стабильная и девелоперская, плюс отдельные для новых фич) и... Теперь я работаю над самим кодом, а не организацией его версий и бекапов на разные даты.

Comment: @Floyat, фишка управления версиями не столько в комментариях к изменениям, сколько в том, что ВСЕ версии исходников, а также все ветки разработки находятся в одном месте. Причём часто ветки имеют смысл даже для индивидуального разработчика, позволяя в разное время работать над разным функционалом, абстрагируясь от прочих изменений. Казалось бы несовместимые правки — правки разных файлов в разных местах — в одну операцию сливаются вместе при объединении веток. В таких случаях, но без такой системы, с контролем вручную, Вы бы тратили неприлично много времени на слияние изменений.