# Командная работа с topic-ветками в Git

Tags: git, git-branch

Только изучаю Git. В голове каша. Не совсем понимаю как командно работать с тематическими/короткоживущим ветками и при этом не превратить проект и репозиторий в хаос.

Подскажите, верная эта схема или нет? 
На сервере 2 ветки: master, develop. Все работают с develop.
Допустим, какому-то сотруднику нужно создать меню.

1. Создаёт новую ветку: `git checkout -b feature-menu`
2. Пушит её на сервер: `git push -u origin feature-menu`
3. Работает, делает коммиты, пуллит чужие и пушит свои изменения
4. Кто-то другой делает `git checkout -b feature-menu origin/feature-menu` и тоже что-то правит
5. Когда работа закончена, сотрудник сливает ветку: `git checkout develop; git merge feature-menu;` Разрешает конфликты
6. Делает `git pull` и `git push` develop-ветки
7. Удаляет ветку локально и удалённо `git branch -D feature-menu; git push origin :feature-menu;`
8. Готово

Доп. вопрос: После того, как сотрудник1 слил и удалил ненужную ветку (пункт 7), у сотрудника2, который тоже работал с этой веткой, после пулла она всё равно локально останется? Нельзя сделать так, что после того как ветка отработала и была удалена с сервера больше у сотрудников она не появлялась нигде. Или это не нужно?

Доп. вопрос 2: Если сотрудник работает над веткой один. Принято ли её пушить на сервер или сливать локально и пушить уже develop?

Comment: Тут вопрос не в том что принято и не принято. У всех по разному принято. 
У кого-то 10 человек в ветке master пишут и горя не знают, у кого-то feature схема, как описано в вопросе. Важно просто понимать к чему та или иная схема может привести, к каким замедлением разработки. И гит используют не только для командной разработки - защита от потери сорцов даёт комфорт. Как то про гит отвечал тут http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/539995#540065

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Схема выглядит правдоподобно. Единственное, что пушить свежосозданную ветку на сервер сразу не обязательно, можно и потом. Удалять ветку лучше так `git branch -d feature-menu`. `-D` удалит ветку в любом случае, а `-d` только если ветка была замерждена.

> Доп. вопрос: После того, как сотрудник1 слил и удалил ненужную ветку (пункт 7), у сотрудника2, который тоже работал с этой веткой, после пулла она всё равно локально останется?

да, локальная ветка никуда не пропадет. Но он может сделать `git pull --prune` -  тогда будет удалена.

> Нельзя сделать так, что после того как ветка отработала и была удалена с сервера больше у сотрудников она не появлялась нигде. Или это не нужно?

Если сотрудник не сделает pull --prune, то она будет у него жить дальше. Но это его личное дело.

> Доп. вопрос 2: Если сотрудник работает над веткой один. Принято ли её пушить на сервер или сливать локально и пушить уже develop?

Можно не пушить. Это его личное дело. Но если он вдруг заболеет или его компьютер решит сходить в ремонт, может быть очень неприятно. Поэтому, если это свои маленькие эксперименты, то обычно не пушат. Если это код, который решает конкретную задачу (которая есть в jira или чему то подобном), то лучше пушить.

Answer (score 5):

Немного дополню отличный ответ KoVadim.

> 4. Кто-то другой делает `git checkout -b feature-menu origin/feature-menu` и тоже что-то правит

Технически можно, главное договориться о таком формате работы, чтобы не было неожиданностей. Если всё-таки оба одновременно закоммитили в ветку, то один делает `git push`, а другой `git pull --rebase` и разрешает конфликты, если будут. Просто `git pull` хуже, т.к. появится мерж-коммит, который *в данной ситуации* никакой информации не несёт, а только засоряет историю.

> 5. Когда работа закончена, сотрудник сливает ветку: `git checkout develop; git merge feature-menu;` Разрешает конфликты
> 6. Делает `git pull` и `git push` develop-ветки

Лучше сначала обновить ветку develop, а потом в неё что-то мержить, иначе есть риск разрешать конфликты два и более раз.

```
git checkout develop
git pull
git merge feature-menu
git push
```

Вообще, мерж ветки — задача ответственная. Нередко право мержить в стабильные ветки есть только у тимлида, который отвечает за ревью кода и за состояние кода в этих самых стабильных ветках. Если у вас есть тестировщики, договоритесь с ними, когда они будут тестировать изменения — до мержа или после. Если вы используете GitHub, GitLab, Bitbucket – подумайте о возможности использовать пулл/мерж-реквесты (pull requests, merge requests). Совсем не обязательно, что для вашего проекта и команды это будет хорошо и полезно, но подумать стоит.

Про работу с ветками рекомендую почитать ответы к этому вопросу: [Как правильно отправить релиз на git?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/573743/181472).
Обязательно прочитайте все, а не только принятый.
Там изложены разные точки зрения и это поможет сформировать более полную картину.