# Как верстать сайт в несколько человек?

Tags: wordpress, github

Добрый день, комрады!
*Ситуация следующая*: есть два человека, которые работают над созданием сайтов, используя CMS Wordpress. Верстаем удаленно друг от друга. Иногда бывает такое, что обоим нужно изменить один и тот же файл. И приходиться ждать пока напарник закончит свою работу, т.к. при моем сохранении все его изменения слетят, и наоборот.
***Вопрос такого порядка***: как нам можно правильно организовать работу, чтобы могли верстать и дальше удаленно, при этом не мешаю друг другу. Слишал, что подобное можно организовать с помощью Github, но толковой статьи так и не нашел. Только о Github Pages, которая подходит только под статику.

Comment: Да, вы делаете свою ветку на гите и пишите там свой код, а друг свою. Мы не мешаете друг другу [Прочитайте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/612346/Работа-в-команде-c-git) или [это.](https://habrahabr.ru/post/75990/)

Comment: Вот какой это - один и тот же? style. css? Сделайте пару @include в нем и пишите каждый в свой файл, делов-то.

Comment: Спасибо. Как я понял, можно сделать репозиторий с проектом (допустим, с папкой темы).

Я забыл уточнить - важно при этом ещё и иметь возможность просматривать результат работы обоих. Есть ли возможность это реализовать?

Comment: В дополнение ко всему вышесказанному - тут описаны бонусы, которые даст git https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/539995#540065

Comment: @entithat только ИМХО - ветки неудобны маленьким командам, особенно новичкам. Гораздо проще работать в одной ветке - просто уметь править конфликты слияния (умение элементарное)

Comment: `и иметь возможность просматривать результат работы обоих` можно - если регулярно сливаться с репозиторием. Обычно такое правило - сделал задачу: слился с репозиторием. После слияния - актуальный код содержит и вашу работу, и работу коллег. Как правило одно слияние занимает 10 секунд - если нет конфликтов. Если они есть то минуту. Работая с отдельными ветками(как советовали выше) вы получите минус - итоговый труд виден не сразу, и слияние веток всё равно потребуется произвести, но получите плюс - решение конфликтов не нужно делать каждый раз при обращении к репе  (а труд коллег просмативаем)

Comment: Что, интересно, можно совместно "верстать" в ВП? Чтобы "верстать" в ВП его нужно знать. Ибо лазить в ядро нельзя, а в ВП имеется механизм плагинов, дочерних тем и вполне чёткая иерархия шаблонов темы. Кроме того никто не запрещает инклудить отдельные функциональные модули темы/плагинов, что при правильно построении совместной работы никак не влияет на напарников.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам необходимо использование системы контроля версий. В комментариях вам предложили использовать Git и я полностью солидарен с этими людьми. Он позволит вам работать над одним файлом одновременно, просматривать кто из вас что сделал, разрешить спорные ситуации если вы в одном файле изменили одну и ту же строку, а также многое другое (например создавать временные версии вашего сайта).

[Ссылка на википедию по Git](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git)

[Ссылка с описанием работы с Git на русском языке](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%92%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-Git)